# Huge SVG draggable HTML/JS

Tags: svg, draggable, frame-rate, smoothing

My goal is to make a whole SVG **draggable** smoothly (in HTML / JS).

I don't want to drag a rect in the SVG, but the whole SVG in the webpage.

The SVG is a map about 10Mo (I can't compress anything).

Do you have any way to help me doing this ?

Thanks !

I tried multiple ways but the best I've done was like 4 FPS.
I also tried by iframe.

Comment: Convert the whole map to canvas and drag the canvas around.

Comment: @RobertLongson The problem is that I need to edit the SVG at any time (highlighting the text for example) but thanks !

Comment: Once you've dragged it around, replace the canvas by SVG again.